# What test is made to deceive someone in Symbaroum?

Tags: social-combat, social-stats, symbaroum

As far as I have been able to find, there is no specific ruling made in the core rulebook on what attribute test is made when attempting to deceive someone. In the supplemental rules table, it is suggested that when trying to persuade a target, the active player should test persuasive<-resolute. In this same table, it is suggested that an attempt to confuse a target could be made with a test of resolute<-resolute. To me, it would follow that based on the attribute descriptions and the existing situations that a persuasive<-cunning test would be best for deception.

Is there a distinct ruling on what a proper deception attempt should look like or is my ruling an acceptable use of the persuasive<-cunning test?

Answer (score 4):

There is no distinct ruling.  As GM I would base the test on how the character is trying to deceive.

If lying, fast talk, or using words of some sort I'd say:  Persuasive<-Resolute.

If it's outsmarting or tricking:  Cunning<-Vigilant.

If using sleight of hand, misdirection, or something physical: Discreet<-Vigilant

Persuasive<-Cunning is perfectly acceptable too, though Persuasive is usually tested against Resolute.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As KorvinStarmast said, feel free to edit your answer to improve it at any time.